# How do you align Checkbox in HTML5/CSS

Tags: css, html, web-applications, web

I'm trying to align my Checkbox with label to center in my little webpage I'm developing but I cannot figure out how, and yes I've googled!

You can view source on my webpage, http://www.sithhappens.net (Load the phone on your mobile though thats where all the CSS is done is for mobile view (Desktop view will come later).

And see the css at http://www.sithhappens.net/iphone.css

Comment: Run your site through an HTML validator. You've got a bunch of problems with it: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Thanks for that, never realized just how horid of a job I did, all fixed up but still cannot seem to get that damn checkbox center :/

Answer (score 0):

Not HTML5 but it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/gYCQz/

CSS:

```
input
{
  display: inline;
}
body
{
  text-align: center;
}
```

HTML4+:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Test" />&nbsp;Test
```

Comment: I tried that, but the thing is staying to the left, instead of going to the center

Comment: Didn't work at all for what I needed, did I do something wrong?

Comment: @user1976501 See Blender's comment above (http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sithhappens.net%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Answer (score -1):

if u want check box in center use this

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" value="Test" />
<div>
```

then u can use text-align(right,left,center) whatever u want.
also u can use

```
<div align="center">


</div>
```

and remove margin-bottom  from all tag give width and height.

Comment: The `align` attribute was dropped a while ago.